# Read .txt file into HTML image map

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner in HTML and am writing a webpage where a canvas is segmented into a grid. Users can mouse over rectangles within the grid and see them highlighted.

I have many coordinates of the rectangles stored in a .txt file (each row has 4 coordinates separated by spaces) and am hoping to read in the file line by line and input them into my code as variables as I might with Python.

```
<area shape="rect" coords="xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax" href="#"...>
```

Any advice/where to point me is much appreciated, as there are too many coordinates for me to input manually!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is AJAX.  You can use something like the following.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "coords.txt", true);

xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if(this.status == 200) {
        // get text contents
        var coords = this.responseText.split("\n");
        coords.forEach(function(coord) {
            // create new area element
            var area = document.createElement("area");
            area.shape = "rect";
            area.coords = coord.replace(/ /g,",");    // replace spaces with commas
            area.href = "#";

            // get your map element somehow
            document.getElementById("myMap").appendChild(area);
        });
    }
};

xhr.send();
```